# How to check that a method is not being called using JUnit Mockito Verify

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class for which I am writing a JUnit test. I am trying to test if a particular method is never called.

```
public class CountryProcess extends AbstractCountryProcess {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CountryProcessor.class);
    private static final Long MAX_FILE = 20l;

    @Override
    protected boolean processCountry(Region region, City city) {
        Long maxFile = region.getRequiredLongValue(SIZE);

        if (maxFile < MAX_FILE) {
            cntDao.addCountryLandMark(city);
        }
        else {
            log.warn("File size was big");
        }

        return true;
}
```

And the test class is:

```
public class CountryProcessTest {

    @Rule
    public final JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();
    private final CntDao cntDao = context.mock(CntDao.class);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(cntDao.class).toInstance(cntDao);
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldIgnoreIfFileSizeBiggerThanPermitted() {
        //some code to make it trigger ELSE statement above...
        verify(cntDao, never()).addCountryLandMark(anyString());
    }
}
```

But this returns the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:
>
> Argument passed to verify() is of type $Proxy4 and is not a mock!
>
> Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
>
> See the examples of correct verifications:
>
> verify(mock).someMethod();
>
> verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
>
> verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();

Any idea how I can fix this in the current context. Please give an example using current code so I get a better idea?

Comment: Is `cntDao` actually mocked in your tests? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Yes sorry I have updated question

Comment: when using the `JUnitRuleMockery` you may better use the `@Mock` annotation instead of direct call to `context` for creating a mock. Of cause this implies tat the variable holding the mock is **not static**.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two mocking frameworks:

- jMock - `JUnitRuleMockery`
- Mockito - `verify` method

Clearly, they are not compatible with each other.
Your verify call looks ok, I believe it will work as soon as it receives a mock created with Mockito (Use `Mockito.mock(CntDao.class)`)

As an alternative to `never` you can use `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions` or `Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions`, but they are less specific.

Comment: Fair. Looks like you have a point but could you give me an example on current code context. It will definitely help

Comment: Updated the answer by mentioning `Mockito.mock`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @Lesiak, here is a reproducible example based on your code with both conditions tested and BDD implementation as well (commented out).

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CountryProcessTest {

    @Mock CountryDAO cntDao;

    @Mock
    Region region;

    @Mock
    City city;

    @InjectMocks
    CountryProcess countryProcess;


    @Test
    void processCountryLargeSize() {
        // given
        given(region.getRequiredLongValue()).willReturn(100L);

        // when
        countryProcess.processCountry(region, city);

        // then
        verifyNoInteractions(cntDao);
        // then(cntDao).shouldHaveNoInteractions(); // BDD implementation
    }

    @Test
    void processCountrySmallSize() {
        // given
        given(region.getRequiredLongValue()).willReturn(10L);

        // when
        countryProcess.processCountry(region, city);

        // then
        verify(cntDao).addCountryLandMark(city);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(cntDao);
        // then(cntDao).should().addCountryLandMark(any()); // BDD implementation
        // then(cntDao).shouldHaveNoMoreInteractions(); // BDD implementation


    }
}
```

The rest of the classes here are provided for reference.

**Region**

```
public class Region {

    private int size;

    public Long getRequiredLongValue() {

        return Integer.toUnsignedLong(size);
    }
}
```

**AbstractCountryProcess**

```
public abstract class AbstractCountryProcess {

    CountryDAO cntDao;

    protected abstract boolean processCountry(Region region, City city);
}
```